# Use the well ordering principle to prove the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Use the well ordering principle to show that if $S \in \mathbb{N}$, then $S=2^k\cdot t$ for some $k, t \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $k\geq 0$ and $t$ is odd.

I know the general idea of a well ordering principle proof is that we need to eye for a contradiction by showing that some set where the hypothesis is false. Once we show that a least element $n$ exists by the WOP, we contradict this by demonstrating that there is another element less than $n$.

It makes sense when I write out my thought, but on paper when trying to make a set, it's not so clear.

This is homework, so can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call a positive integer $n$ **bad** if it cannot be expressed in the desired form. We want to show there are no bad positive integers.

Suppose to the contrary that the set $B$ of bad positive integers is non-empty. Then there is a *smallest* bad integer $b$.

Note that $b$ cannot be odd, for by definition all odd positive integers are good. So $b$ is even. Let $b=2c$. Note that $c\lt b$. Note also that $c$ is bad. For if $c$ were good, we would have $c=2^i t$, for some $i\ge 0$ and odd $t$, and then $\dots$.